# How to handle embedded commas and quotes in a regular expression search string

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have a CSV file and I want to convert

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, maecenas porttitor congue massa`

To

```
<text>
   <name>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</name>
   <element>consectetuer adipiscing elit</element>
   <desc> maecenas porttitor congue massa</desc>
</text>
```

I'm able to get this simple case done with the search expression being:

```
^([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),
```

- `^` - look for the beginning of the line
- `([^,]*),` - look for zero or more characters that are **not** a comma, followed by a comma, and group it (do this 3 times)

And the replacement expression as:

```
<text>\n   <name>$1</name>\n   <element>$2</element>\n   <desc>$3</desc>\n</test>\n
```

This works for the simple case.  However, sometimes a value in the CSV has embedded commas, in which case the value has quotes around it.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, "consectetuer, adipiscing elit", maecenas porttitor congue massa
```

So the second value (which will be an <element>) should end up with:

```
<text>
   <name>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</name>
   <element>consectetuer, adipiscing elit</element>
   <desc> maecenas porttitor congue massa</desc>
</text>
```

That is, <element> should have the embedded comma.  I don't need to keep the quotes.

And then to make it a bit messier, the string might also contain quotes, which are escaped with quotes (or at least that's how the CSV is given to me, which was generated from a google sheet and saved as a CSV)

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, "and he said, ""no way!"", to my astonishment", maecenas porttitor congue massa
```

I want to end up with:

```
<text>
   <name>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</name>
   <element>and he said, "no way!", to my astonishment</element>
   <desc> maecenas porttitor congue massa</desc>
</text>
```

So <element> should have the embedded commas and escaped quotes (with the escape character, which is a second quote, removed).

I got lost on trying to create the search regular expression.

Comment: What you want to do here is have your google guy export this as tab-delimited :)  Totally doable with regular expressions, but this is already a somewhat complicated problem you do not want to further complicate

Comment: Exactly, the embedded commas and then the embedded quotes makes it harry.  Not sure I can get a tab delimited file.  That would be nice.

Comment: For fun, I took the file I was given and changed the commas to tabs (except the embedded commas) and the escaped quotes to regular quotes, and my regex was straightforward.  Thanks for the idea.  Hopefully I can get the next file as a tsv instead of csv.  But I'm still curious if the original file could still be fixed with one regex.

Comment: There are lots of questions on SO where people try to use RegEx for CSV files. As is the case here, it tends to be when people realise that there are fringe cases that they come to ask a question. They might even be able to hack their way around the quoted values, until they realise that if the quoted value contains quotes, then they have to be escaped. The proper answer is to write code use a CSV parsing library rather than trying to use a RegEx replace in an editor.

Comment: Yes, I understand it's a fringe case.  I'm just trying to use the search/replace dialog that exists in the editor that allows regexp.  I'm not going to rewrite the editor.

Comment: (Note: if you don't tag my name, I won't see your response.)

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you rewrite the editor. I'm suggesting you write a 30 line program to convert it, rather than using the wrong tool for the job, and then finding another fringe case because you didn't solve the problem correctly the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines should work:

```
^\s* ( " (?:[^"]|(?:""))*" |(?:[^,]*)), \s*(" (?:[^"]|(?:""))*" |(?:[^,]*)), \s*(" (?:[^"]|(?:""))*" |(?:[^,]*))
```

It's the same pattern basically...Repeated 3 times.
Whitespace, followed by a capturing group that is either a sequence of non-commas, or preferably, a `"` followed by (anything that is not a `"`) OR a `""`, lastly followed by a closing quote.

You'll need to check the "Ignore Whitespace" button at the link below.

[regex storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cs*%28%3f%3a+%22+%28%3f%3a%5b%5e%22%5d%7c%28%3f%3a%22%22%29%29*%22+%7c%28%3f%3a%5b%5e%2c%5d*%29%29%2c+%5cs*%28%3f%3a+%22+%28%3f%3a%5b%5e%22%5d%7c%28%3f%3a%22%22%29%29*%22+%7c%28%3f%3a%5b%5e%2c%5d*%29%29%2c+%5cs*%28%3f%3a+%22+%28%3f%3a%5b%5e%22%5d%7c%28%3f%3a%22%22%29%29*%22+%7c%28%3f%3a%5b%5e%2c%5d*%29%29&i=Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%2c+%22and+he+said%2c+%22%22no+way!%22%22%2c+to+my+astonishment%22%2c+maecenas+porttitor+congue+massa&o=)

Using a {3} notation instead of repeating the pattern 3 times can work and could even be used to replace the "" but I'm a little unsure about how to get at repeated capture groups through the UI

Answer (score -1):

I am no visual-studio-code expert. But I think this can be done **without regex**

Following python code should give an idea

Key is to ignore the commas until the quotes are paired.

```
data = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, "and he said, ""no way!"", to my astonishment", maecenas porttitor congue massa'
items = data.split(',')
result = []

for i in range(len(items)):
    if (len(result) == 0):
        result.append(items[i])
        continue

    # If last item has odd number of quotes, it needs pairing - Ignore commas
    if (result[-1].count('"') % 2):
        # Append to last element
        result[-1] += ',' + items[i]
    else:
        result.append(items[i])

print("\n".join(result))
```

Output

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
 "and he said, ""no way!"", to my astonishment"
 maecenas porttitor congue massa
```

Please let me know if you need more explanation for the code

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain clearly.  I'm in an editor and the lines in the editor are CSV - one record per line.  I'm trying to change each line as explained above.
I'm using the search/replace dialog in VSCode which is just an input field for the search string.  Not sure I can run any python code or code of any kind for the search field.  I can't do any looping.  I'm sure if I had to write code to do the matching, that'd be a breeze, but I'm limited to regex.